# Questions of limited/no applicability to others

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989547/calculating-offset-from-two-hex-strings) was answered to the asker's satisfaction, but it involved large amounts of guesswork (reverse engineering an algorithm), is extremely specific to a particular situation, and is unlikely to be useful to anyone else - even *without* the OP's determination to delete pertinent information.

How should such a question be handled?

- Downvoting and/or closing (probably as "unclear what you're asking") leaves the post intact, with a reasonably relevant reason for closing. But the asker has what they came for, there's no need to clarify or improve anything, no hope of reopening, and even if it was rolled back to restore the OP's sample data, nobody else would find the question useful.
- Flagging for deletion ("very low quality"?) seems like a big hammer to use, potentially antagonising a new user and annihilating an upvoted and accepted answer.

[Possibly related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82406/close-a-low-quality-question-or-flag-it-or-do-both), though the original SO post has been deleted.

Comment: I think this calls for a custom close reason, maybe similar to the old "Too Localized" text.  That is probably the best fit here as the other options are not exactly perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vote to close it with the following *Off Topic* reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.